# If a radio in a set div is clicked. Swap the selected radio with #radioselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, radio-button

On clicking a radio in radiogroup2 the selected radio should swap with the radio with the id selected radio. tried doing it with .clone but maybe wrong choice

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/5 nearly correct updated to http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/6/ still not working

```
$("div.radiogroup2 input[name='domain_ext']").click(function() { //only if a the radio in radiogroup to are clicked take radio and swap with id='radioselected'
    if  ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).after('#radioselected').add(this);
        $('#radioselected').after(this);
    }
});
```

i have selected the radio to hide with another script and have dressed it with css and the label of the radio is visible. in the same form i have 3 sections of the same radio group (grouped by name='') when a radio in the div radiogroup2 is selected, i want this radio (label and css) to swap with the radio with the id='radioselcted'

So. in short.

Click a radio in div with class 'radiogroup2'.
This radio swaps with radio with id 'selectedradio'

Comment: will this clone and swap the radio element or just the class/css

Comment: You have syntax errors. Run your fiddle with the Chrome or Firebug Console open to see them.

Comment: [18:06:27.590] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. @ http://jsfiddle.net/js/moo-clientcide-1.3.js?WinterIsBackButAtLeastItsShining:3714

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if a radio is checked. It's always going to be checked if it's clicked. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here. Please clarify your question above.

Comment: Fiddle updated above.

Comment: i have selected the radio to hide with another script and have dressed it with css and the label of the radio is visible. in the same form i have 3 sections of the same radio group (grouped by name='') when a radio in the div radiogroup2 is selected, i want this radio (label and css) to swap with the radio with the id='radioselcted'

Comment: Please clarify your question above, not here in the comments.

Comment: have updated it into table form so it is clear. so any radio clicked in the second row should switch positions with the radio in the first row with the id 'selectedradio' http://jsfiddle.net/DCC66/6/